# Display previous text when call function next time?

Tags: javascript, jquery

In my project, I need to show previous text when call function next time?
My code is ..

HTML code is :-

```
<div id="notes">
    <textarea rows="21" cols="38" id="notes_id" placeholder="Enter your notes here..." onclick="current_time('videoPlayer')" onblur="play_video()" >
    </textarea>
</div>
```

javascript:-

```
function current_time (player_id) {             
    var player = _V_(player_id);
    var secs = player.currentTime();
    var hours = Math.floor(secs / (60 * 60));

    var divisor_for_minutes = secs % (60 * 60);
    var minutes = Math.floor(divisor_for_minutes / 60);

    var divisor_for_seconds = divisor_for_minutes % 60;
    var seconds = Math.ceil(divisor_for_seconds);

    var time    = hours+ '::' +minutes+ '::' +seconds;
    player.pause();
    document.getElementById("notes_id").value = "Current Time :- " +time+ "\n";
}
```

Comment: You'll either have to store the value inside a properly scoped variable (or to keep track of all answers, use an array), and set it when the function runs, or use a database. If you save the variable with JS, you'll lose the value if the page reloads (unless you use HTML5 localStorage).

Comment: if you want only the previous value you could use hidden variable. Assign the prev value to it when new value is generated.

Answer (score 1):

You could simply use `+=` instead of `=`, so when clicking the text will be added to current content:

```
document.getElementById("notes_id").value += "\nCurrent Time :- " +time+ "\n";
```

Comment: This will keep appending (which if the OP is fine with, yay good answer!), what if he ONLY wants the last input?

Comment: and how can i make it "\nCurrent Time :- " +time+ "\n" in readable mode.